# Filter Doxygen output with grep

Tags: grep, doxygen, tcsh

I want to filter the doxygen warnings with grep, to supress the undocumented parameter warning for certain parameters. I am trying this:

```
doxygen doxycfgfile | grep -v "parameter x"
```

however this seems to have absolutely no effect on the output. Neither the lines containing `parameter x` are suppressed nor all other lines. The output appears to be exactly the same.

I am using tcsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably this is because the undocumented parameter warning messages are being written to standard error (*stderr*), rather than standard out (*stdout*). With the pipe (`|`) you are only piping stdout to `grep`'s input.

You could try doing something like

```
doxygen doxycfgfile |& grep -v "parameter x"
```

From the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/):

> If `|&` is used, the standard error of `command1` is connected to `command2`'s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

Note, this was added in Bash 4, so for earlier versions you will have you use `2>&1 |` in place of `|&`.

Alternatively, you could just get rid of the standard error output, using something like

```
doxygen doxycfgfile 2>/dev/null
```

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/24953) on askubuntu was the source for my answer.

Comment: thank you it works, now i just have to modify my regex to match the whole errormessage generated for missing parameter, where parameter x is the only parameter. but thats not part of the question. Otherwise this works like a charm